# access text between two tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have tags coded as such:

```
<strong>Email: </strong> testing<br />
```

How would one access the `testing`.

I have tried:

`$("strong").closest("br").text()` so far.

Comment: Any `node` (text nodes included) must have a parent, so, what's the parent of the text node `testing` ? Is it `<body />`?

Comment: @Hitmands the parent is a `p` tag

Comment: var text = $('p').text();
var test = text.split(':');

You can use parent node to get text and split it to get the text you want. Hope this will help.

Comment: Shouldn't you kind of know all these values before and make the view based on data model? Not the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

**Demo:** https://jsbin.com/vezepul/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
   var totalText = $("p").html();
   var startPos = totalText.indexOf("</strong>") + "</strong>".length;
   var endPos = totalText.indexOf("<br");
   var targetText = totalText.substring(startPos,endPos).trim();
   alert(targetText);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><strong>Email: </strong> testing<br /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uncanny how close your answer is to the one from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30131101/616443