# API Postman Response-Extracting content between two tags

Tags: javascript, postman

Below is the postman response which has decoded from its raw data.
For all lines, Content located between two fact tags are to be extracted.

```
<div class="stl_01" style="left:7.6167em;top:6.1257em;"><span class="stl_05 stl_06 stl_07"><fact value="1%" class="accepted">百分之一</fact> </span></div>
<div class="stl_01" style="left:7.6167em;top:7.6257em;"><span class="stl_05 stl_06 stl_07"><fact value="2%" class="accepted">百分之二</fact> </span></div>
<div class="stl_01" style="left:7.6167em;top:9.1257em;"><span class="stl_05 stl_06 stl_07"><fact value="3%" class="accepted">百分之三</fact> </span></div>
<div class="stl_01" style="left:7.6167em;top:10.6257em;"><span class="stl_05 stl_06 stl_07"><fact value="4%" class="accepted">百分之四</fact> </span></div>
```

Below snipped is used for decoding raw data.

```
var parsedBase64=CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ContentText);
console.log(parsedBase64);

var parsedStr = parsedBase64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.log("Testing for content:" + parsedStr + "End content");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex select all text between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167279/regex-select-all-text-between-tags)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130453/how-to-capture-a-string-between-two-tags. The rest is just processing the input and output of your data.

Answer (score 0):

my string manipulation approach ...

provided that you have an html string, such as

```
    htmlStr = `<div class="stl_01" style="left:7.6167em;top:6.1257em;"><span class="stl_05 stl_06 stl_07"><fact value="1%" class="accepted">百分之一</fact> </span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:7.6167em;top:7.6257em;"><span class="stl_05 stl_06 stl_07"><fact value="2%" class="accepted">百分之二</fact> </span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:7.6167em;top:9.1257em;"><span class="stl_05 stl_06 stl_07"><fact value="3%" class="accepted">百分之三</fact> </span></div>
                <div class="stl_01" style="left:7.6167em;top:10.6257em;"><span class="stl_05 stl_06 stl_07"><fact value="4%" class="accepted">百分之四</fact> </span></div>`
```

first define a function that returns the array of indices of a substring occurancies in a string, such as

```
function indexes(source, find) {
 if (!source) {
  return [];
 }
 // if find is empty string return all indexes.
 if (!find) {
// or shorter arrow function:
// return source.split('').map((_,i) => i);
  return source.split('').map(function(_, i) { return i; });
 }
 var result = [];
 for (i = 0; i < source.length; ++i) {
// If you want to search case insensitive use 
// if (source.substring(i, i + find.length).toLowerCase() == find) {
  if (source.substring(i, i + find.length) == find) {
   result.push(i);
  }
 }
 return result;
}
```

then find the position of the substrings `class="accepted">`
and `</fact>`

```
start = indexes(htmlStr,'class="accepted">')
end = indexes(htmlStr,'</fact>')
```

finaly find the substrings inside fact tags.

```
for(let i=0;i<start.length;i++){
    console.log(htmlStr.substring(start[i]+16,end[i]))
}
```